# C# RegEx to extract a value from a string

Tags: c#, regex

Can someone assist me to extract the price from the below string using a RegEx c#. I've tried few examples and seems I can not get it done and I know it is very basic but I can't get it.

I could not find a way to escape : and ".

String:
`"ouioieu":"Canister","price":"59.0000","sku":"DECC500","barcode_gtin sj`h

Expected value: 59.0000

I need the complete code block as once working, I will use the same method for other places.

(Why marked as duplicate due to similar answer with double quotes?. But this one, the main issue was colon and I needed a complete answer and already received. )

Comment: What have you tried ? you dont need regex, just cut "," then ":"

Comment: This looks like `JSON`... *don't* use `regex` for `JSON`

Comment: far better use a json parser

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a disclaimer, your data looks a lot like a fragment from JSON.  If so, you should consider using a JSON parser to extract things from it.  Assuming you absolutely need to use a regex here, then consider the pattern:

```
.*"price":"(.*?)"
```

This will capture everything which followed `price` in quotes.  Here is a sample code:

```
string str = @"""ouioieu"":""Canister"",""price"":""59.0000"",""sku"":""DECC500"",""barcode_gtin sjh""";
var m = Regex.Match(str,@".*""price"":""(.*?)"".*");
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

**Output:**

```
59.0000
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Works fine ... thanks.

Comment: how can we access the values from month and day (?<Month>\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s)(?<day>\d{1,2})